# save and retrive image from mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This code is now working. i want to save an image in database please help me how i can work on this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    CaptionTextBox.Text = OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName

    ' ImagePictureBox.Image = image.FromFile(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    updateRecord("insert into uploadimages(caption,image) values('" + CaptionTextBox.Text + "', '@ImagePictureBox' )")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean it "is not" working? What's wrong (specific errors/results), and what have you tried to fix it......what does "updateRecord" do?

Answer (score 0):

```
     Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim abc As String

    private sub from1()
      cn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database = school"
    cmd.Connection = cn
            cn.Open()
    end sub

 Private Sub images()
        Dim arrImage() As Byte
        Dim strImage As String
        Dim myMs As New IO.MemoryStream
        If Not IsNothing(Me.PictureBox5.Image) Then
            Me.PictureBox5.Image.Save(myMs, Me.PictureBox5.Image.RawFormat)
            arrImage = myMs.GetBuffer
            strImage = "1000"
        Else
            arrImage = Nothing
            strImage = "NULL"
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO admision(name, photo) VALUES('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'," & _
                               strImage & ")"

        If strImage = "1000" Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add(strImage, MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = arrImage

        End If

        MsgBox("Data save successfully!")
        clear()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cn.Close()

    End Sub
```